# launch spark/spring-boot job on yarn cluster with kerberos enable

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, kerberos

I want to use spring-boot and spark together in a Yarn cluster with kerberos enable. (I am sprint-boot newbie)

my prerequisite :

- I can't use spark-submit, the application is launch this way :

  ```
  java -jar <my_jar>
  ```
- I build the jar with spring-boot-maven-plugin.

Here is my simplified code :

```
@SpringBootApplication public class A implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    B b;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(A.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {           
        b.run();    
    }    
}
```

my B class:

```
@Component
public class B{
 public void run() {
  SparkSession ss = createSparkSession();
  Dataset<Row> csv = readCsvFromHDFS()
  //  business logic here
  writeCsvToHdfs();
 }
}
```

This work well on localhost with master set to `local[*]`, the main problem is when i try to set the sparkSession master to Yarn.
My idea was to pass all parameters from spark-submit to my spark session to avoid using spark-submit.
My sparkSession is created with this way :

```
SparkSession.builder()
.master("yarn")
.appName("appName")
.config("HADOOP_CONF_DIR", "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf")
.config("SPARK_CONF_DIR", "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf")
.config("spark.driver.cores", "5")
.config("spark.driver.memory", "1g")
.config("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
.config("spark.logConf", "true")
.config("spark.submit.deployMode", "client")
.config("spark.executor.cores", "5")
.config("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address", "XXXX:8050")
.config("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", "XXXX")
.config("spark.hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos")
.config("hadoop.security.authorization","true")
.getOrCreate()
```

at the moment my error is :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
...

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

my kerberos ticket is valid before launching application.

I think that my core-site, hdfs-site, yan-site ... is ignored because the SparkSession should be able to retrieve the information needed by himself.

I try to export it but it change nothing :

- export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf
- export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/
- export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client

There is a better way to use spark + spring-boot + yarn + kerberos together and that respect my prerequisite  ?

my version :
Java 8
HDP : 2.6.4
Spark : 2.3.2
Spring-boot : 2.3.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to solve that

1. You can handle keytab explicitly with `UserGroupInformation` and run your main code in privileged context

```java
private String principal;
private File keytab;

public UserGroupInformation ugi() {
    final org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
    conf.set(CommonConfigurationKeysPublic.HADOOP_SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Kerberos");
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
    return UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(principal, keytab.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

And then

```
ugi.doAs(() -> {
    // Start Spring context here
});
```

2. Doing spark-submit from java

You can locate your jar via reflection and submit it through `deploy.SparkSubmit` class, with provided keytab and principal.

3. You can embed a script which will handle submit inside your jar with `embeddedLaunchScript` in `spring-boot-maven-plugin`
   Note: you would have to start it with `./app.jar` not `java -jar app.jar`

```xml
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <goals>
      <goal>repackage</goal>
      <goal>build-info</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
  <mainClass>your.Main</mainClass>
  <embeddedLaunchScript>src/main/sh/spark-submit.sh</embeddedLaunchScript>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Where `spark-submit.sh` is your own implementation of spark-submit similar to 2)

Comment: i tried embeddedLaunchScript method, the problem is same as using spark-submit with spring-boot-maven-plugin. he is unable to find my class : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. because a fat-jar and the jar from spring-boot-maven-plugin is not organized the same way.

Comment: I believe that you should use not your own main class, but JarLauncher in this case.

Comment: right but I get compatibility problem. with the embeddedLaunchScript, it seam there are a probleme with the snakeyml version. spring-boot use version 1.26 and spark-submit version 1.18. i have try to force the version to 1.19 , 1.20 ..., neither one nor other  accept it.
Instead of using UserGroupInformation for authentification, I place configuration files to the classpath ( core-site, hdfs-site, mapred-site and yarn-site), I am now well authentificate but i also encouter compatitibility version with jersey libraries. spring-boot use jersey v 2.30.x and spark/yarn 2.22.2 . any idea ?

Comment: @maximeG you have to exclude conflicting dependecies, do you really use jersey with spring-boot? You also can try relocating packages you use in order to avoid conflict with cluster classpath